# Firefox X11 from Ubuntu on Windows not working

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firefox, x11

I am trying to run Firefox (or any other browser) through an X11 connection from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

I am using VcXsrv 1.20.6.0

My Firefox version I see through the bash terminal is:

```
(env) flx@pc:/etc/ssh$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 74.0
```

When I try to start Firefox from the bash I get the following error:

```
(env) flx@pc:/etc/ssh$ firefox
Exiting due to channel error.

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x1E0057,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateEffects) Channel error: cannot send/recv


(firefox:16625): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=f6c6eb9e4e7543fa90e8fb64fbdd8983 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
[Parent 16625, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-LE_x6q/firefox-74.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 23
```

I am quite stuck here, do you have any ideas what I could try to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @Roudcore's answer

`wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.0/firefox-52.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2
sudo tar xjf firefox-52.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox-sdk/bin/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox`

Answer (score 1):

Try to `service dbus start` before starting firefox, after that `dbus-launch` should work properly

As alternative, i would recommend you to use firefox 52.

52 version works correctly.

Comment: wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.0/firefox-52.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2
sudo tar xjf firefox-52.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox-sdk/bin/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox